# Is it good to start your car up until the engine temperature gets to the middle?

Tags: engine, warmup

I usually start my car up for around 10-20 minutes before actually driving it to warm it up. I know it's not needed anymore with newer cars but is it better to do it?

Comment: [Related](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/7847/how-long-should-i-let-me-car-warm-up-in-the-winter?rq=1) if not a total duplicate. **Bold** text is created with two asterisks on either side of the word.  [See this](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more details.

Comment: My vote is that it's a duplicate, since the questions are so similar and the answers are exactly the same.

Comment: Absolute waste of fuel.